# How to find the maximum value of this trigonometric function?

Tags: mathematical-optimization, trigonometry

The known conditions are:

```
Sin[2 α + β] == 
 2 Sin[β], 0 < α < π/2, 0 < β < π/2
```

Find the maximum value of `Tan [β]`

```
Maximize[{Tan[β], Sin[2 α + β] == 2 Sin[β], 
   0 < α < π/2, 0 < β < π/2, 
   0 < α + β < π}, {α, β}] // FullSimplify

Solve[{TrigFactor[
   SubtractSides[Sin[2 α + β]] == 2 Sin[β]], 
  0 < α < π/2, 0 < β < π/2, 
  0 < α + β < π}, α]
```

There were no results using the above methods or steps.

Comment: Solve for $\beta$ in terms of $\alpha$ and then find the value of $\alpha$ that maximizies $\tan(\beta)$.  Plotting the known condition as a contour plot will give you the range of possible values for $\beta$ and give you another approach to find the maximum of $\tan(\beta)$ which I think is $\tan \left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}\right)$.

Comment: `Sqrt[3]/3 .= 0.57735` is the maximum of `Tan[β]`,but I don't how to use MMA to get this.

Comment: Oops!  Thanks, @cvgmt.  You are correct.  I mistakenly put in the maximum in $\tan$ rather than the associated value of $\beta$.

Comment: The syntax `TrigFactor[SubtractSides[Sin[2 α + β]] == 2 Sin[β]]` returns a syntax error (and I'm not sure what you're actually trying to do with it, so I don't know how to correct it.)

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Find the relationship between these two angles

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `NMaximize`

```
NMaximize[{Tan[β], Sin[2 α + β] == 2 Sin[β], 0 < α < π/2 && 0 < β < π/2 && 
   0 < α + β < π}, {α, β}]
{0.57735, {\[Alpha] -> 0.523599, \[Beta] -> 0.523599}}
```

If the exact result is absolutely necessary, then one can build on the numerical result:

```
Maximize[{Tan[β], Sin[2 α + β] == 2 Sin[β], 4/10 < α < 6/10 && 
   4/10 < β < 6/10}, {α, β}]
{1/Sqrt[3], {α -> π/6, β -> π/6}}
```

**supplement**

**This expression works.** Please don't ask me why.

```
Maximize[{Tan[β], Sin[2 α + β] == 2 Sin[β], 0 < α < π/2 && 
    0 < β < π/2}, {α, β}] // Simplify
{1/Sqrt[3], {β -> π/6, α -> π/6}}
```

Calculation in the traditional way:

```
f = Tan[β];
g = Sin[2 α + β] - 2 Sin[β];
L = f + λ g;
sol = First @ Solve[{Grad[L, {α, β}] == 0 && g == 0 && 0 < α < π/2 && 0 < β < π/2 && 0 < α + β < π}, {α, β}, {λ}]
{α -> π/6, β -> π/6}

 f /. sol
1/Sqrt[3]
```

It seems `Maximize` is buggy.

Comment: This method is also very good, it can calculate the maximum value. But it's best to calculate the exact value of its maximum value!

Comment: ```4/10 < α < 6/10 && 
   4/10 < β < 6/10```How did these two ranges come from?

Comment: As already mentioned, from the numerical calculation.

Comment: ```Maximize[{Tan[\[Beta]], 
   And[Sin[2 \[Alpha] + \[Beta]] == 2 Sin[\[Beta]], 
    0 < \[Alpha] < \[Pi]/2, 
    0 < \[Beta] < \[Pi]/2]}, {\[Alpha], \[Beta]}] // FullSimplify```

Comment: ```Maximize[{Tan[\[Beta]], 
   Sin[2 \[Alpha] + \[Beta]] == 2 Sin[\[Beta]] && 
    0 < \[Alpha] < \[Pi]/2 && 
    0 < \[Beta] < \[Pi]/2}, {\[Alpha], \[Beta]}] // FullSimplify```

Comment: ```Maximize[{Tan[\[Beta]], Sin[2 \[Alpha] + \[Beta]] == 2 Sin[\[Beta]], 
   0 < \[Alpha] < \[Pi]/2 && 
    0 < \[Beta] < \[Pi]/2}, {\[Alpha], \[Beta]}] // FullSimplify```

Comment: All three of the above situations are acceptable

Answer (score 6):

A contour plot of the condition shows that $\beta$ will need to be between 0 and around 0.5:

```
ContourPlot[Sin[2 α + β] == 2 Sin[β], {α, 0, π/2}, {β, 0, π/2},
  FrameLabel -> (Style[#, Bold, 24, Italic] &) /@ {"α", "β"}]
```

[image: Contour plot of condition]

We can solve for $\beta$ in terms of $\alpha$:

```
(sol = Simplify[Solve[Sin[2 α + β] == 2 Sin[β], β], 
  Assumptions -> 0 < α < π/2]) // TableForm
```

[image: Solutions for beta in terms of alpha]

Now plot $\beta$ over the values of $\alpha$ for each of the 4 solutions to find legitimate solutions:

```
Plot[β /. #, {α, 0, π/2}, Frame -> True,
  FrameLabel -> (Style[#, Bold, 18, Italic] &) /@ {"α", "β"}] & /@ sol
```

[image: Plot of solutions for beta given legitimate alpha values]

We see that only the second solution results in the required values for $\beta$.

```
Maximize[{Tan[β], 0 < α < π/2} /. sol[[2]], α]
(* {1/Sqrt[3], {α -> π/6}} *)
```

And so the value of $\beta$ that maximizes $\tan(\beta)$ given the equality condition is

```
β /. sol[[2]] /. α -> π/6
(* {π/6} *)
```

Answer (score 3):

#### Update 2

Using a custom [`DisplayFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DisplayFunction.html) we can display the three-way relation between `α`, `β` and `Tan[β]` in a single `ContourPlot` with multiple vertical axes (`displayFunction` and `options2` defined below):

```
ContourPlot[Sin[2 α + β] == 2 Sin[β], {α, 0, π/2}, {β, 0, π/2}, 
 DisplayFunction -> displayFunction, Evaluate @ options2]
```

[image]

---

***displayFunction:***

```
displayFunction = Show[#, Graphics[{ColorData[97] @ 2,
  Cases[Normal @ #, Line[x_] :> 
   {PointSize[Large], Line[{#, Tan@#2} & @@@ x],
    ColorData[97]@1, Point@MaximalBy[Last]@x,
    Dashed,
    Arrowheads[{{.01, 0,                 
      Graphics[{Text[Style[π/6, 14], Offset[{-10, 0}, {0, 0}], {1, 0}]}]}}], 
    Arrow[{{0, 1} #, #} &@First[MaximalBy[Last]@x]],
    ColorData[97]@2, 
    Point@{#, Tan@#2} & @@@ MaximalBy[Tan@*Last]@x,
    Arrowheads[{{.01, 1, 
      Graphics[{Text[Style[1/√3, 14], Offset[{10, 0}, {0, 0}], {-1, 0}]}]}}], 
    Arrow[{{#, Tan@#2}, {π/2, Tan@#2}} & @@ First[MaximalBy[Tan @* Last]@x]]},
    All]}]] &;
```

***options2:***

```
options2 = {
   FrameStyle -> {ColorData[97] /@ {1, 2}, Automatic}, 
   PlotPoints -> 100,
   PlotRange -> {{0, Pi/2}, {0, .8}},
   PlotRangeClipping -> False,
   FrameLabel -> {Style[#, 18] & /@ {"β", "tan(β)"}, {Style["α", 18], None}},
   FrameTicksStyle -> FontSize -> 14,
   FrameTicks -> {
     {Charting`ScaledTicks[{Identity, Identity}, 
         "TicksLength" -> {.03, .015}][##, 6] &, 
      Charting`ScaledTicks[{Tan, ArcTan}, 
         "TicksLength" -> {.03, .015}][##, 6] &},
      {{0, π/6, π/2}, Automatic}},
   GridLines -> {{Pi/6}, None}, 
   ImageSize -> Large};
```

---

#### Update 1

```
cp = ContourPlot[Sin[2 α + β] == 2 Sin[β], {α, 0, π/2}, {β, 0, π/2}];
```

For a visual analysis, we can construct a `BSplineFunction` using the coordinates of the contour line in `cp`:

```
BSF = First @ Cases[Normal @ cp, Line[x_] :> BSplineFunction[x], All];
```

We can use `BSF` with `ParametricPlot3D` to display `α`, `β` and `Tan[β]` on the three axes:

```
ParametricPlot3D[{#, #2, v Tan@#2} & @@ BSF[t], {t, 0, 1}, {v, 0, 1}, 
  BoxRatios -> 1, Mesh -> None, 
  BoundaryStyle -> Directive[Thick, Red], 
  AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 16] & /@ {"α", "β", Tan@β}),
  ImageSize -> Large, Lighting -> "Neutral", ViewPoint -> {2, -2, 1.5}]
```

[image]

We can also use `BSF` with `ParametricPlot` to display the relations between `α`, `β` and `Tan[β]` in a 4-panel plot with shared axes (see below for the definitions of `legends` and `options`):

```
Legended[#, legends] & @
 ParametricPlot[{BSF[t],
   {-Tan[t π/2 ], t π/2  },
   {-Tan[t π/2 ], -Tan[t π/2 ]  },
   {#, -Tan @ #2} & @@ BSF[t]},
  {t, 0, 1},
  Evaluate @ options]
```

[image]

---

***Legends:***

```
labels = {Sin[2 α + β] == 2 Sin[β],
   Tan @ β,
   Defer[Tan @ β == Tan @ β],
   Sin[2 α + Tan@β] == 2 Sin[Tan@β]};

legends = MapThread[Placed[LineLegend[#, #2, LabelStyle -> 16], #3] &]@
   {List /@ ColorData[97] /@ Range[4],
    List /@ labels, 
    {{.75, .95}, {.1, .95}, {.15, .05}, {.75, .05}}};
```

***Axis annotations:***

```
ClearAll[axisAnnotations]

axisAnnotations[{lbl1_, lbl2_}] := Arrowheads[{{-Large, 0}, {Large, 1},
    Sequence @@ MapThread[{Small, #2 /. -1 -> 0, 
      Graphics[{Text[#, Offset[{#2 10, 0}, {0, 0}], {-#2, 0}]}]} &, 
       {{lbl1, lbl2}, {-1, 1}}]}];

axesstyle = {axisAnnotations[Style[#, 14] & /@ {"tan(β)", "α"}], 
  axisAnnotations[Style[Rotate[#, -Pi/2], 14] & /@ {"tan(β)", "β"}]};
```

***Ticks:***

```
ClearAll[framed]
framed = Framed[ #, Background -> White, FrameStyle -> None] &;

ticks = {{{-π/2, π/2}, {-1/Sqrt[3], framed[1/Sqrt[3]]}, 
    0, {π/6, framed[π/6]}, π/2}, 
  {{-π/2, π/2}, {-1/Sqrt[3], framed[1/Sqrt[3]]}, {π/6, framed[π/6]}, π/2}};
```

***Prolog:***

```
prolog = {Arrowheads[{{.025, .85}}], Dashed,
   Arrow @ Partition[{{π/6, π/6}, 
      {-1/Sqrt[3], π/6},
      {-1/Sqrt[3], -1/Sqrt[3]},
      {π/6, -1/Sqrt[3]}}, 2, 1, 1],
    Gray, Arrow /@
    (Partition[{{##}, 
       {-Tan@#2, #2}, {-Tan@#2, -Tan@#2}, {#, -Tan@#2}} & @@ 
       BSF[#], 2, 1, 1] & /@ {.15, .75})};
```

***Options:***

```
options = {RegionFunction -> (-π/3 <= # < π/2 &),
   MeshFunctions -> {# &}, Mesh -> {{π/6}},
   MeshStyle -> Directive[Red, PointSize@Large], 
   ImagePadding -> 60,
   GridLines -> {{-1/Sqrt[3], π/6}, {π/6, -1/Sqrt[3]}}, 
   PlotRange -> {{-π/3, π/2}, {-π/3, π/3}},
   AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
   AxesStyle -> (Directive[AbsoluteThickness[2], #] & /@ axesstyle),
   PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.08],
   Prolog -> prolog,
   Ticks -> ticks,
   TicksStyle -> 12, 
   ImageSize -> 700};
```

---

#### Original answer

`Tan @ b` is monotonic over `0 < b < π/2` as can be verified using [`FullSimplify`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FullSimplify.html) or [`FunctionMonotonicity`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FunctionMonotonicity.html)

```
FullSimplify[0 < Tan' @ b , 0 <= b < π / 2]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

```
FunctionMonotonicity[{Tan @ b, 0 <= b < π / 2}, b]
```

> ```
> 1
> ```

Thus, we can replace `Tan @ b` with `b` in the first argument of `Maximize[...]` in OP to get an exact (and fast) result:

```
FullSimplify @
 Maximize[{b, 
   And[Sin[2 a + b] == 2 Sin[b], 0 < a < π/2, 0 < b < π/2, 
    0 < a + b < π]}, {a, b}]
```

> ```
>  {π/6, {a -> π/6, b -> π/6}}
> ```

Then, simply take the `Tan` of the first argument of the solution

```
Tan[First @ %]
```

> ```
> 1/Sqrt[3]
> ```

Comment: ```FullSimplify @
 Maximize[{b, 
   And[Sin[2 a + b] == 2 Sin[b], 0 < a < π/2, 0 < b < π/2, 
    0 < a + b < π]}, {a, b}]```Why is And connected in the middle of this sentence?

Comment: @csn899, ti works the same with or without using `And` to wrap all constraints. (I had a separate line defining constraints with `constraints = And[....]` and copy/pasted its rhs into `Maximize[{b, ...},...]` to save a line when I posted)

Comment: ```Maximize[{\[Beta], 2 Sin[\[Beta]] == Sin[2 \[Alpha] + \[Beta]], 
   0 < \[Alpha] < \[Pi]/2, 0 < \[Beta] < \[Pi]/2, 
   0 < \[Alpha] + \[Beta] < \[Pi]}, {\[Alpha], \[Beta]}] // \
FullSimplify```Why can't we get the correct result for this?

Comment: @csn899, interesting -- `And[...]` is needed after all  and `FullSimplify` works in myterious ways.

Comment: What is the real difference between And?

Comment: no idea why `Maximize` returns unevaluated if we remove `And` or `FullSimplify`.

Comment: ```Maximize[{Tan[\[Beta]], Sin[2 \[Alpha] + \[Beta]] == 2 Sin[\[Beta]], 
   0 < \[Alpha] < \[Pi]/2 && 
    0 < \[Beta] < \[Pi]/2}, {\[Alpha], \[Beta]}] // FullSimplify```

Comment: ```Maximize[{Tan[\[Beta]], 
   Sin[2 \[Alpha] + \[Beta]] == 2 Sin[\[Beta]] && 
    0 < \[Alpha] < \[Pi]/2 && 
    0 < \[Beta] < \[Pi]/2}, {\[Alpha], \[Beta]}] // FullSimplify

Comment: Maximize[{Tan[\[Beta]], 
   And[Sin[2 \[Alpha] + \[Beta]] == 2 Sin[\[Beta]], 
    0 < \[Alpha] < \[Pi]/2, 
    0 < \[Beta] < \[Pi]/2]}, {\[Alpha], \[Beta]}] // FullSimplify

Comment: All three of the above situations are acceptable

Comment: ```Maximize[{\[Beta], 
   2 Sin[\[Beta]] == Sin[2 \[Alpha] + \[Beta]] && 
    0 < \[Alpha] < \[Pi]/2, 
   0 < \[Beta] < \[Pi]/2 && 
    0 < \[Alpha] + \[Beta] < \[Pi]}, {\[Alpha], \[Beta]}] // \
FullSimplify```But this cannot calculate the maximum value

Comment: Isn't And equivalent to&&?

Answer (score 2):

Any algebraic equation in trigonometrics with integer multiples   transformes into an algebraic equation by the stereographic projection

```
  t<->tan phi/2
```

In this case

> the hopefully correct transform

> ```
>       Maximize[{y, (2 x + y)/(1 + (2 x + y)^2) == (4 y)/(1 + y^2), 
>        0 <= {x, y} <= 1}, y, Reals] /. 
>                {x -> Tan[\[Alpha]/2],  y -> Tan[\[Beta]/2]}
> ```
>
> results
>
> ```
>        {\[Piecewise] -Root[3 #1^3+2 Tan[\[Alpha]/2]-14 #1^2
>       Tan[\[Alpha]/2]+#1 (3+16 Tan[\[Alpha]/2]^2)&,1] 
>              0<=Tan[\[Alpha]/2]<=1
>
>
>       -\[Infinity]    True
>
>       ,{Tan[\[Beta]/2]->\[Piecewise]  -Root[3 #1^3+2
> Tan[\[Alpha]/2]-14 #1^2 Tan[\[Alpha]/2]+#1 
>   (3+16 Tan[\[Alpha]/2]^2)&,1]    0<=Tan[\[Alpha]/2]<=1 
>
>
>  Indeterminate    True
> ```

No comment, verification left to the reader.

Comment: How did these replace with x and y？

Comment: The easiest and obviously failsafe way is, to not change the names of the variables. Mathematicians get headaches about this way, because it only works with twosided double bookkeeping. This is the central point of all calculus and algorithmical mappings: In practice local variables are not kept in different name spaces. The old school of Euler, Lagrange and Jacobi generally used Latin and Greek characters or a tick. Both technics are not  Mathematica style , one because 26 characters are a too small set, the other, Wolfram did not differentiate between superscript and Power  but had an  y'

Comment: A right idea, but badly realized. The true way is `2 Cos[\[Alpha]] Cos[\[Beta]] Sin[\[Alpha]] + 
   Cos[\[Alpha]]^2 Sin[\[Beta]] - Sin[\[Alpha]]^2 Sin[\[Beta]] == 
  2 Sin[\[Beta]] /. {Sin[\[Alpha]] -> 2 x/(1 + x^2), 
  Cos[\[Alpha]] -> (1 - x^2)/(1 + x^2), Sin[\[Beta]] -> 2 y/(1 + y^2),
   Cos[\[Beta]] -> (1 - y^2)/(1 + y^2)}` and then `Maximize[{2 y/(1 - y^2), -((8 x^2 y)/((1 + x^2)^2 (1 + y^2))) + (
    2 (1 - x^2)^2 y)/((1 + x^2)^2 (1 + y^2)) + (
    4 x (1 - x^2) (1 - y^2))/((1 + x^2)^2 (1 + y^2)) == (4 y)/(
   1 + y^2), 0 <= {x, y}}, {x, y}]`.

Answer (score 0):

Making use of `TrigExpand`, this can be done in 13.2.1 on Windows 10 in such a way.

```
Maximize[{Tan[\[Beta]], TrigExpand[Sin[2 \[Alpha] + \[Beta]] == 2 Sin[\[Beta]]], 
  0 <= \[Alpha] <= \[Pi]/2, 0 <= \[Beta] <= \[Pi]/2}, {\[Alpha], \[Beta]}]
```

> `{1/Sqrt[3], {\[Beta] -> \[Pi]/6, \[Alpha] -> \[Pi]/6}}`

and a warning

> Maximize::ztest: Unable to decide whether numeric quantities {-5 [Pi]-24 ArcTan[Root[1+Times[<<2>>]+Times[<<2>>]+Times[<<2>>]+Power[<<2>>]&,1,0]],7 [Pi]-24 ArcTan[Root[1+Times[<<2>>]+Times[<<2>>]+Times[<<2>>]+Power[<<2>>]&,3,0]],-11 [Pi]-24 <<1>>,[Pi]-24 ArcTan[Root[1+Times[<<2>>]+Times[<<2>>]+Times[<<2>>]+Power[<<2>>]&,3,0]],Sqrt[3]-3 Tan[4 ArcTan[Root[<<1>>&,3,0]]]} are equal to zero. Assuming they are.